# Correct preposition: "By" or "of"

Tags: prepositions

I saw the following sentence in my grammar textbook as a grammatically incorrect sentence:

> *We lost the game because of a mistake of one of our players*.

And it’s corrected in the following way:

> *We lost the game because of a mistake by one of our players*.

But I think the original sentence is correct, although I can’t say why. I think we need “by” if we want to write the sentence as follows:

> *We lost the game because of a mistake done by one of our players*.

Is the original sentence grammatically correct? Why?

Comment: The mistake was *made* (not *done*) by the player, but your logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

'We lost the game because of a mistake of one of our players.'

Your original sentence is fine.

Your final version will be fine too if it uses 'made', as StephenS has suggested, or 'committed'.

'We lost the game because of a mistake made/ committed by one of our players.'